# How to add HardConstraint for min and max count per group in OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm new in OptaPlanner.

I need to divide the list of works between employees, but the number of work performed by one employee should not be less or more than the specified values.
For example, one employee cannot perform less than 10 and more than 30 jobs per day.

Source code

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@PlanningEntity
public class Job {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "employeeRange")
    private Employee employee;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@PlanningEntity
public class Inspector {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "employee")
    private List<Job> jobs;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@PlanningSolution
public class Plan {

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "employeeRange")
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Job> jobs;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;

}
```

Also another question:

How can I combine several constraints into one.
For example, one employee can perform from 10 to 30 jobs per day. A business trip lasts from 2 days and, accordingly, during this period he can perform a total of 20 to 60 jobs.

I read the documentation, but I'm not sure if the `count() countDistinct() min() max()` is suitable for this purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your domain, I do not see any fields to determine the Job's date, so I am assuming all jobs share the same date. Using [Constraint Streams](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html), you can model your minimum and maximum jobs constraints like so:

```
public class MyConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
                minimumJobsPerDay(constraintFactory),
                maximumJobsPerDay(constraintFactory)
        };
    }

    Constraint minimumJobsPerDay(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Inspector.class)
                            .filter(inspector -> inspector.getJobs().size() < 10)
                            .penalize("Employee performing less than minimum jobs per day",
                                      HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                                      inspector -> 10 - inspector.getJobs().size());
    }

    Constraint maximumJobsPerDay(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Inspector.class)
                            .filter(inspector -> inspector.getJobs().size() > 30)
                            .penalize("Employee performing more than maximum jobs per day",
                                      HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                                      inspector -> inspector.getJobs().size() - 30);
    }
}
```

For your second question, the [Compose Constraint Collector](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#collectorsComposition) can be useful for combining constraints (although it not needed for your example). For your example (with an additional problem fact class `BusinessTrip`):

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BusinessTrip {
    private Employee employee;
    private LocalDate start;
    private LocalDate end;
}
```

and changing Job so it has a date:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@PlanningEntity
public class Job {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    private LocalDate date;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "employeeRange")
    private Employee employee;

}
```

The constraint can be model like so:

```
Constraint jobsDuringBusinessTrip(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(BusinessTrip.class)
        .join(Employee.class, Joiners.equal(BusinessTrip::getEmployee, employee -> employee))
        .join(Job.class, Joiners.overlapping(
              (trip, employee) -> trip.getStart().atStartOfDay(),
              (trip, employee) -> trip.getEnd().atStartOfDay(),
              job -> job.getDate().atStartOfDay(),
              job -> job.getDate().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay()),
              Joiners.equal((trip, employee) -> employee, Job::getEmployee))
        .groupBy((trip,employee,job) -> trip,
                 (trip,employee,job) -> employee,
                 ConstraintCollectors.countTri())
        .filter((trip, employee, jobCount) -> jobCount < 20 || jobCount > 60)
        .penalize("Over or under job count during business trip",
                  HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I checked again and it seems there is a problem. For example, when there are 10 jobs and 5 employees, then it distributes the jobs among 2 employees. But at the same time it shows that there are violations of the constraints. `Indictments:
        -5hard: justification (Employee) has 1 matches:
            -5hard: constraint (Min Count)
        -5hard: justification (Employee{id=1}) has 1 matches:
            -5hard: constraint (Min  Count)
        -5hard: justification (Employee{id=2}) has 1 matches:
            -5hard: constraint (Min Count)`

Comment: The violations look correct for the given constraints (employee 1 and employee 2 have 5 jobs, which is less than the minimum of 10, causing two indictments of -5hard). Question: does the minimum jobs constraint apply if an employee is assigned no jobs? If so, then another constraint need to be added that select employees with no jobs.

Comment: First of all let me thank you for the quick response. Answer to the question - No, min and max count constraints must be apply only for employees for which jobs was assigned.. Also I asked the similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72882869/how-to-add-constraints-for-solving-scheduling-problem-in-optaplanner I would be grateful if you can help me with this question

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```java
public class CustomConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[]{minNumberConflict(constraintFactory), maxNumberConflict(constraintFactory)};
    }

    Constraint maxNumberConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Job.class).groupBy(Job::getEmployee, count()).filter((employee, count) -> count > 30).penalize("Max Count", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD, (employee, count) -> count - 30);
    }

    Constraint minNumberConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Job.class).groupBy(Job::getEmployee, count()).filter((employee, count) -> 10 > count).penalize("Min Count", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM, (employee, count) -> 10 - count);
    }
}
```