# How to add constraints for solving scheduling problem in OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to solve the following problem with OptaPlanner:

- It is necessary to divide list of jobs between employees.
- There is a minimum and maximum amount of job that 1 employee can perform. (For example, 5 - 10)
- Each job has a fixed time to complete (30 minutes)
- Also, the works are located in different places and, accordingly, there is a cost matrix (`List<Cost>` only the time to reach the place of work is important). I'm using GraphHopper for building cost matrix.
- The employee has a work schedule. For example, 9 hours (540 minutes).
- Jobs should be divided between employees in such a way that, taking into account the time it takes to complete (30 mins for each job) it and the cost matrix, the total time does not exceed the work schedule (540 minutes).

Source code:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@PlanningEntity
public class Job {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "employeeRange")
    private Employee employee;

    private Coordinate coordinate;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@PlanningEntity
public class Employee {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;

    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "employee")
    private List<Job> jobs;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@PlanningSolution
public class Plan {

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "employeeRange")
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Job> jobs;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;

}

@Data
public class Cost {

    private Job from;

    private Job to;

    private Long time;

}
```

Here is the Constraint class:

```java
public class CustomConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
                minInspectionNumberConflict(constraintFactory),
                maxInspectionNumberConflict(constraintFactory)
        };
    }

    Constraint minInspectionNumberConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Employee.class)
                .filter(employee -> employee.getApplications().size() < 5)
                .penalize("Min Count",
                        HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                        employee -> 5 - employee.getApplications().size());
    }

    Constraint maxInspectionNumberConflict(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(Employee.class)
                .filter(employee -> employee.getApplications().size() > 10)
                .penalize("Max Count", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                        employee -> employee.getApplications().size() - 10);
    }
}
```

How can I solve such a problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your domain; from `Cost`, I can see you require the Jobs to be ordered, but `Job` does not have any problem properties (i.e. non-planning variable fields) that can be used to determine the order (for example, a datetime field).

To enforce an order,there are two different models you can use:

- the chained model, where each `Job` point to the previous `Job` (and the first `Job` points to `Employee`). This is explained by https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#chainedPlanningVariable and https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/design-patterns/design-patterns.html#chainedThroughTimePattern .
- Using `@PlanningListVariable`, where each `Employee` is assigned an ordered `List` of jobs (and each job goes to exactly one employee). This changes `Employee` to the `@PlanningEntity` with a `@PlanningListVariable` for jobs, and `Job` to a `shadow entity` (changing its `@PlanningVariable` to an `@InverseRelationShadowVariable`). An example of this is https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing .

The final form of the constraints will vary depending on which model is used.